# Determine whether MudTextField is valid without updating UI

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I'm using Blazor and MudBlazor.

If I call [`myMudTextField.Validate()`](https://mudblazor.com/api/textfield) then it validates the field and updates the UI - shows validation errors, etc.

Can I determine whether the field is valid without updating the UI? For example, something like `myMudTextField.IsValid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can implement custom validations with the use of yields as a field validation, if that's what you need. Here it's an example of how i use it!

Page.razor:

```
<MudTextField Validation="@(new Func<int, IEnumerable<string>>(PtoVtaStrength))" T="int" Pattern="^[+-]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)$" Placeholder="123"  Required="true" RequiredError="PtoVta required" Text="@PtoVta.ToString()" />
```

Page.razor.cs

```
private IEnumerable<string> PtoVtaStrength(int value)
{
    if (value <= 0)
    {
        yield return "IsValid";
        yield break;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to check if it's valid or not with mud blazor, at the moment you need to implement custom validation On property changed!

Page.Razor:

```
<MudTextField Validation="@(new Func<int, IEnumerable<string>>(PtoVtaStrength))" T="int" Placeholder="123"  Required="true" RequiredError="Punto de venta requerido" ValueChanged="@OnPtoVtaChanged" Text="@PtoVta.ToString()" />
```

Page.razor.cs:

```
private Task OnPtoVtaChanged(int value)
{
    //Do your validation here
    //if true
    PtoVta = value;
    //else
    PtoVta = 0
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this will be useful to some people. For me, I don't want to add custom validation, I want to rely on what I already have. But I want to perform validation without updating the UI. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @lonix The only thing i can imagine to solve that is modifying onPropertyChanged of each field you want to validate, then you can validate each property in particular, did you already try it that way?

Comment: That is another good idea! But not for my use case - I think the problem is mudblazor does not allow to that. I hope in a future version.

Comment: @lonix i understand, and yeah they should have 2 methods, one to know if it's valid or not and another to validate, i will edit my answer to add the "OnPropertyChanged" solution until mudblazor update this!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is... it's not supported. [Until](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/5541) it is, see Leandro's answer for some workarounds.